# Date Render Issue in ExtJS

Tags: grails, extjs

I am using Grails with *extJS* in my project. I have a date column in my display page. It gets displayed as  `2010-09-29T04:00:00Z`.

After i used the below to render the date, I got the date displayed as `NaN/NaN/NaN`

```
{header: "Date", width: 90, renderer : ('m/d/Y'), sortable:true,  dataIndex: 'date'}
```

Am I missing something here?

Thanks!

Comment: Try looking at this thread in the ExtJS forum - they seem to discuss the same or a similar problem: http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?68703-Formatting-date-column-in-GridPanel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Thanks Ergo/Chau. It seems that some work only for Firefox and not for IE7. The code mentioned in my query works with Firefox and I get the right output. However, with IE7 it doesn't. Had to make the below change for it to work in IE7.

```
{name: 'dte', dateFormat:'c', type:'date'},
```

and in `ColumnModel`:

```
{header: "Date", width: 90, dataIndex: 'dte',
        renderer : Ext.util.Format.dateRenderer('m-d-Y')
},
```

Comment: Thanks for adding in your solution, always good to know- and glad it works!

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following function to your code:

```
function RENDER_date(value){return value ? value.dateFormat('m/d/Y') : '';}
```

Then set the renderer property:

```
renderer: RENDER_date
```

Comment: Thanks Ergo/Chau.It seems that some work only for Firefox and not for IE7. The code mentioend in my query works with Firefox and I get a right output. However, with IE7 it doesnt.
Had to make the below chnage for it to work in IE7.

Answer (score 0):

Add to `format: 'm/d/Y'` to your grid and store config.